# Angular.js: Inline expression in ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, visibility

I want to control ng-hide without having to write dedicated method in controller. Something like:

```
<div ng-hide="session.filter==''">{{session.filter}}</div>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is and it is easy to verify, just add an [E2E test](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) and give it a try, that will be faster than posting a question and  waiting for an answer. Plus, you'll improve your testing suite :)

Comment: How will E2E help me to guess the syntax or to guess whether the variant exists at all? ng-hide="session.filter==''" does not work as written.

Comment: It should. Are you sure you're setting `$scope.session.filter` to anything? Could you post the code that sets it?